# SQL to Filter on multiple dimensions with a many-to-many relationship

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby, entity-relationship

In my rails app I have three tables to deal with the many-to-many relationship between courses and categories

- courses
- course_categories_courses
- course_categories

I have groups of categories, and I want to allow filtering of the listing of the courses by categories through an interface like:

Location

- very near
- near
- far

Type

- short
- medium
- long

To search for medium types either near or far I had thought of using:

```
SELECT distinct courses.* 
FROM `courses` 
  inner join course_categories on 
    course_categories_courses.course_category_id = course_categories.id 
    and (
      course_categories.id in ('medium') 
      and course_categories.id in ('near', 'far')
    )
```

but that's not working. Anyone able to point me in the right direction please?

Answer (score 0):

You generally want to put to 'relationships' as join conditions, and values (literals) to filter by in the where clauses

ex. join condition - `on course_categories_courses.course_category_id = course_categories.id`

ex. where clause - `where course_categories.id in ('near', 'far')`

So you might want to rewrite your query that way.  But more than that, how can the both of these possible be true?

```
(course_categories.id in ('medium') and course_categories.id in ('near', 'far'))
```

Is that what you intend?

Comment: This may be the crux of the issue. My course_categories_courses table holds a course_categories_id and a course_id, using my example data, there are records for:

 - course 1 | medium
 - course 1 | near
 - course 2 | far
 - course 2 | short

I want it to return just course 1. At the moment, it returns neither.

Comment: i think jny got to the point.  the second (near/far) part should be `location`, not `id`

Answer (score 0):

You have to join both tables and you are using id field where type and location (according to your description) should be used

```
SELECT distinct courses.* FROM `courses` 
inner course_categories_courses on course_categories_courses.course_category_id = courses.course_category_id
inner join course_categories on 
course_categories.id = course_categories_courses.id
where  (course_categories.type in ('medium') and course_categories.location in ('near', 'far'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Syntactaclly the query you wrote is fine. There are two unusal things about it as other's have noted

1. Filter on a Inner join. (Typically done in the where but perhaps you have your reasons)
2. `course_categories.id in ('medium')`. Most would expect a number here but perhaps this is just for demonstration purposes.

The reason for it "not working"

1. You're getting an error that you've swept under the rug in your ruby that you're not sharing
2. Its working there simply are no records matching your criteria.

**Ways to debug**.

1. Run it in Workbench (or some other client) and check the results
2. If there are no errors and no record are returned run some queries in workbench

   `Select count(*) from course_categories  where course_categories.id in ('medium')`

   `Select count(*) from course_categories  where course_categories.id in ('near', 'far')`
3. If you got the results you wanted in Workbench then its probably your client (Ruby) code, bad connection string perhaps?

Comment: Thanks for this. Yes, for demo purposes, it's an id. I've been running in Workbench - so know that it is ok from that angle. The queries you wrote return 1 and 2 repectfully, which is expected. Thanks for your contribution though.

Comment: @Denseflux So you get the expected in WorkBench but not in Ruby? Sounds like a Ruby issue to me. Sorry I'm not a Ruby person.